# wp_editor add media button not working

Tags: plugin-development, uploads, media-library, wp-editor

I am creating a wordpress plugin(backend activity, form submission) where Instead of inserting plain text, users need to add images and html texts so, I need to use wp_editor instead of  form element. code for wp_editor I used below.

```
wp_editor( '', 'instructions', $settings = array('textarea_name' => 'instructions', 'textarea_rows' => '5') );
```

I can see "add media" button but, when I click on it, nothing (no media library pop up) appears however, if I go to Posts-> Add a new post and over here same the "add media" button poping up media library normally, where user can insert or select already uploaded image files.

Comment: do you display this editor in an admin page ?

Comment: yes, e.g. http://localhost:8888/gyan2/wp-admin/admin.php?page=add-quiz

Comment: look the console of the browser to look if there is a JavaScript error. e.g. with Firefox : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console

Comment: nothing, look like button does not triggered anything at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that you are creating a custom admin page at `?page=add-quiz`, in this case before calling the `wp_editor` function you also have to enqueue the CSS / Js files for it with the `wp_enqueue_media()` function.

So at the end you should have

```
wp_enqueue_media();
wp_editor( '', 'instructions', $settings = array('textarea_name' => 'instructions', 'textarea_rows' => '5') );
```

A clever way to do it would be inside an action like

```
function prefix_my_custom_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_media();
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_my_custom_admin_scripts');
```

Again assuming that you don't have this hook already.

Comment: it did not work . however, yes I guess there is something to do with wp_enqueue_media

Comment: I found out problem, this code was preventing add media popup , soon I removed it , things start working well.
<!--
<script tst="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" src="<?php echo plugins_url('/js/jquery.min.js', __FILE__); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
-->